# how to select the last row insert by a specific iduser

Tags: mysql, database, select, max, where-clause

Hello I want to get a specific userid who enter specific data. When X user enter data and save h will be the last row. But How I take the last row of exemple my user id = 16. Mnay user can insert data after him but I want only the last row of my user id 16.

```
SELECT * 
from
    projetstaches
        inner join
    timesheets
        on (timesheets.timId = projetstaches.prtTimeSheetId)
        inner join
    users
        on (users.usrId = timesheets.timUserId)
WHERE
    users.usrId = 16  AND `prtTimeSheetId` = ( 
SELECT MAX(  `prtTimeSheetId` ) 
FROM projetstaches )
```

When I do something like this it's return blank cause the last user who entered something is 7.

So how do I retrieve my last user = 16?

Here what look my table ( this is a old ver but good to know how it's look like the data now is more completed but the name of table its the same)

http://pastebin.com/6LBwGtc3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subquery needs to use a join to select the highest `prtTimeSheetId` for this user, not the entire table.

```
SELECT * 
from
    projetstaches
        inner join
    timesheets
        on (timesheets.timId = projetstaches.prtTimeSheetId)
        inner join
    users
        on (users.usrId = timesheets.timUserId)
WHERE
    users.usrId = 16 
AND prtTimeSheetId = (
    SELECT MAX(preTimeSheetId)
    from 
        projetstaches
            inner join
        timesheets
            on (timesheets.timId = projetstaches.prtTimeSheetId)
            inner join
        users
            on (users.usrId = timesheets.timUserId)
    WHERE users.usrId = 16)
```

Comment: doest work only get me 1 information for the last timID . I only have 1 timID ( primary key) but is linked to prtTimesheetID ( and i can have many) exemple I have number 501 in timesheet ( timId) but in projetstache (timeSheetID0 for the number 500 i have tuesday, monday, saturday.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'inner join timesheets on (timesheets.timId = projetstaches.prtTime' at line 15

Comment: Sorry, cut/paste problem, I missed the `from` line.